# Lookup value next to the first number in column

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I need a formula that can find the date in a cell next to another that has the first number in the column.

In column A I have dates and in column B onward I have stock prices. The dates goes back to 1990 daily, but not all the stock prices starts there. All of the prices end at 20-05-2015.

For all the stocks, I need to find out how many days they have been traded. I have the end date, but I need to look up the start date.

Therefore, I need a formula that says "Lookup the first cell which is numeric in column B, and take the corresponding cell in column A".

Thank you

Comment: What have you got so far?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use an array formula like this, assuming you have up to 1000 rows of data

`=INDEX($A1:$A1000,MATCH(TRUE,ISNUMBER(B1:B1000),0))`

confirm with <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>ENTER</kbd>

Comment: Thank you SO much!!! :)
I have tried to implement this "index-match", however it havent worked for me. But now it does - thanks to you! I really appreciate the help!